# Return a grouped DataFrame like in SQL

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a database with tables that look as follows:

```
stream_history
+ ----------+-------- +
+ played_at + song_id +
+ --------- + ------- +

songs
+ ------- + --------- + -------- +
+ song_id + song_name + album_id +
+ ------- + --------- + -------- +

artists
+ --------- + ----------- +
+ artist_id + artist_name +
+ --------- + ----------- +

artists_songs (relational table)
+ --------- + ------- +
+ artist_id + song_id +
+ --------- + ------- +

albums
+ -------- + ---------- +
+ album_id + album_name +
+ -------- + ---------- +
```

Let's say I want to get the song infos to all my streamed songs. I do this with the following SQL statement:

```
select distinct played_at, song_name, sh.song_id, artist_name, 
        artists.artist_id, album_name
    from stream_history as sh
    join songs on songs.song_id = sh.song_id
    join art_songs as ars on ars.song_id = songs.song_id
    join artists on artists.artist_id = ars.artist_id
    join albums on albums.album_id = songs.album_id;
```

I get an output that looks like this:

```
+ --------- + --------- + --------- + ----------- + ----------- + ---------- +
+ played_at + song_name + song_id   + artist_name + artist_id   + album_name +
+ --------- + --------- + --------- + ----------- + ----------- + ---------- +
+ DATE_1    + Song_A    + SONG_A_ID + ARTIST_A    + ARTIST_A_ID + ALBUM_A    +
+ DATE_1    + Song_A    + SONG_A_ID + ARTIST_B    + ARTIST_B_ID + ALBUM_A    +
+ DATE_2    + Song_B    + SONG_B_ID + ARTIST_C    + ARTIST_C_ID + ALBUM_B    +
+ DATE_3    + Song_C    + SONG_C_ID + ARTIST_D    + ARTIST_D    + ALBUM_C    +
+ --------- + --------- + --------- + ----------- + ----------- + ---------- +
```

Note that there are 2 entries  for `DATE_1` because `Song_A` features 2 different artists.

Now I want to analyze these entries with pandas in python. The things I'm most interested in are finding out how much streams every artist has (or in SQL terms: `DISTINCT COUNT(artistid)`) and how often every single song has been streamed (`DISTINCT COUNT(song_id)`).

I want the DataFrames to look like this:

```
+ ----- + --------- + ------- + ----------- + --------- + ---------- + 
+ count + song_name + song_id + artist_name + artist_id + album_name + 
+ ----- + --------- + ------- + ----------- + --------- + ---------- +
```

where `count` is either the count of `artist_id` or `song_id`, depending on what I currently want to display.

For this, I've tried the following things:

```
artist_streams = df.groupby('artist_id', as_index=False)

artist_streams = df.groupby('artist_id').size().to_frame(name='count')

artist_streams = df.groupby('artist_id').count()

artist_streams = df.value_counts('artist_id').groupby('artist_id')

artist_streams = df.groupby('artist_id').value_counts('artist_id')
```

The returned DataFrame only had two columns: `artist_id` and their repsective`count` , instead of the desired output that is similar to the SQL one above. I expected to find a way that returns a result that's equal to the given SQL statement.

I can circumvent this by filling my dataframe via this statement instead of the above one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(sh.song_id) as count, artist_name
    FROM stream_history as sh
    JOIN artists_songs ON artists_songs.song_id = sh.song_id 
    JOIN artists on artists.artist_id = artists_songs.artist_id
    group by artists.artist_id
    order by count desc;
```

This immediately gives me a DataFrame with the desired format. This isn't the way I want to handle this, since this means having a select statement for every DataFrame I want to create.

How can I get an output in pandas that looks like my desired one?

---

Here's a small code example:

```py
[In 1]: df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['2021-07-22 14:36', 'Song A', 1, 'Artist A', 1], 
    ['2021-06-23 20:28', 'Song B', 2, 'Artist B', 2],
    ['2021-06-23 20:28', 'Song B', 2, 'Artist C', 3],
    ['2021-06-23 20:35', 'Song C', 3, 'Artist A', 1]
    ],
    columns=['Played at', 'Song', 'Song_id', 'Artist', 'Artist_id'])
df
[Out 1]:
          Played at    Song  Song_id    Artist  Artist_id
0  2021-07-22 14:36  Song A        1  Artist A          1
1  2021-06-23 20:28  Song B        2  Artist B          2
2  2021-06-23 20:28  Song B        2  Artist C          3
3  2021-06-23 20:35  Song C        3  Artist A          1

[In 2]: grouped = df.groupby('Artist_id')
grouped 
[Out 2]: <pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x00000175D9761D80>

[In 3]: grouped2 = df.groupby('Artist_id').size()
grouped2
[Out 3]:
Artist_id
1    2
2    1
3    1
dtype: int64

[In 4]: artist_streams = df.groupby('Artist_id').size().to_frame(name='count')
artist_streams
[Out 4]:
           count
Artist_id       
1              2
2              1
3              1

[Out 5]: # this is the desired output format for grouping by artist_id
ArtistCount   Song_id     Artist  Artist_id
          2         1   Artist A          1
          1         2   Artist B          2
          1         3   Artist C          3

[Out 6]: # this is the desired output format for grouping by song_id
SongCount     Song    Song_id       Artist  Artist_id
        1   Song A           1    Artist A          1
        2   Song B           2    Artist B          2
        1   Song C           3    Artist A          3
```

The other inputs (as stated above) yield similar results as the ones provided here.

Comment: `How can I get an output in pandas that looks like my desired one?` What format is that exactly? Please show, don't describe.

Comment: FYI, I removed additional questions from this question. Feel free to post them separately, one question at a time

Comment: @Emkay perhaps I'm not getting your example, but where's the row with Song C in your expected output? Why did it disappear?

Comment: @amiola my apologies, I edited my code example. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @Emkay what I mean is that either 'Song' or 'Song_id' are ambiguous wrt 'Artist_id' (and viceversa), so I don't see how you can get such outputs. Perhaps it might be useful if you can post the whole SQL queries you'd use to get such results. Or - which might be the case - I'm totally misunderstanding the example.